# Issue with importing database in pgAdmin (.sql format)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to reload PostgreSQL database into pgAdmin. The base is in .sql format (db.sql)
When I'm trying to reload it, the following problem appears:

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump.
>   Please use psql.

I've never imported database before, so I don't know what to do.

How could I use psql? Should I modify db.sql file somehow?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is worth reading

Comment: Could these commands be executed in pgAdmin and on which step? Or they should be applied to the .sql file using the terminal of my laptop?
Thank you for the support! :)

Comment: I tried the following in the console:

psql -U user_test -d database_test -f db.sql

Then a password is required, but I don't know what to enter.